# Problema com auto focus

Tags: jquery

Galera criei um input personalizado, e não consigo fazer o autofocus funcionar.

Segue o código:

```js
$('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('focus');

$("#inputNormal3").trigger('focus');
```

```css
.form_campos_simples {
  width: 250px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.control-label {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label,
.form-group-select.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos {
  height: 31px;
  color: #484848;
  z-index: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #484848;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.form_campos:hover,
.form_campos:focus {
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group'>
<label class='control-label' for='inputNormal'>NOME 1</label>
<input  type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_simples' id='inputNormal' name='nome' autofacus>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<label class='control-label' for='inputNormal3'>NOME 2</label>
<input  type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_simples' id='inputNormal3' name='nome' autofacus>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<label class='control-label' for='inputNormal'>NOME 3</label>
<input  type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_simples' id='inputNormal' name='nome' autofacus>
</div>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Troca o `trigger('blur')` por `trigger('focus')`

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior faça uma resposta, mesmo que curta isso parece que resolve o problema ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está utilizando o evento `blur` que é invocado ou invoca a perda do foco. Para atribuir o foco utilize o evento `focus`.

Há duas maneiras de você chamar o evento, pode ser utilizando o `trigger('focus')` ou ainda somente `focus()`.

```
$('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function (e) {
    //...
});
$("#inputNormal").trigger('focus');
```

## O que é blur?

[Blur](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp) é o evento que ocorre quando um `input`perde o foco.

## O que é focus?

[Focus](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focus.asp) é o evento que ocorre quando um `input` recebe o foco.

### Como invocar ou manipular os eventos?

- `on('focus' ou 'blur', function () { })`: utilizado para alterar o comportamento padrão do evento.
- `focus()` ou `blur()` ou ainda `trigger('focus' ou 'blur')`: invoca o evento para o elemento.

Comment: ok, o problema e que coloquei apenas um input para exemplo. E como faço isso em um formulário cheio de input que utilizam esse jquey? como irei dar focus em um input expecifico ?

Comment: Basta acessar o input utilizando jQuery e invocar o evento como mencionei acima, por exemplo, acessar o elemento pela sua id: `$("#meuInput").focus()` ou `$("#meuInput").trigger('focus')`.

Comment: ok deu certo muito obrigado, vou editar minha pergunta aqui